# Notification intent to single activity without recreation

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, notifications

I have webview application and I have two types of GCM notifications: "new thread" and "new reply to thread". So when user clicks on one of notification, in this moment webview should open one of appropriate web page. 
I applied

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

and added `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to activity manifest. That how I avoid webview recreation and whole process of reloading page. But I have a problem: how to listent Intent in MainActivity to further webview location changes?

If `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` is not flags that I need, then please tell me how avoid full webview recreaction in `void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` ? `savedInstanceState == null` in all times, how can I save last webview instance?

Comment: your app in in background or killed?

Comment: do you want onNewIntent?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
```

Is the solution. Thanks to pskink